# Best way to append text to file in dm-script

Tags: file, file-writing, dm-script

What is the best way to append line(s) to a file?

---

Currently I am using the following script:

```c
/**
 * Append the `line` to the file given at the `path`.
 * 
 * @param path 
 *     The absolute or relative path to the file with 
 *     extension
 * @param line
 *     The line to append
 * @param [max_lines=10000]
 *     The maximum number of lines to allow  for a file 
 *     to prevent an infinite loop
 */
void append(string path, string line, number max_lines){
    number f = OpenFileForReadingAndWriting(path);

    // go through file until the end is reached to set the 
    // internal pointer to this position
    number line_counter = 0;
    string file_content = "";
    string file_line;
    while(ReadFileLine(f, file_line) && line_counter < max_lines){
        line_counter++;
        // file_content += file_line;
    }
    
    // result("file content: \n" + file_content + "{EOF}");
    
    // append the line
    WriteFile(f, line + "\n");
    CloseFile(f);
}
void append(string path, string line){
    append(path, line, 10000);
}

string path = "path/to/file.txt";
append(path, "Appended line");
```

For me it seems a little bit odd to read the whole file content to just append one line. If the file is very big, this probably is very slow<sup>1</sup>. So I guess there is a better solution of this. Does anyone know this solution?

---

**Some background**

My application is written in [python](/questions/tagged/python) but executed in *Digital Micrograph*. My `python` application is logging its steps. Sometimes I am executing [dm-script](/questions/tagged/dm-script) from python. There I have no possibility to see what is going on. Since there is a bug, I need something to find out what is going on. Therefore I want to add logging to `dm-script` too.

This also explains, why I want to open and close the file every single time. This takes more time, but I don't care about execution speed while debugging. The logs will either be removed or switched off for the normal version, as usual. But on the other hand I am executing `dm-script` and `python` alternating so I have to prevent `python` blocking the file for `dm-script` and the other way around.

---

<sup>1</sup>As written in the background, I am not really interested in speed. So the current script is enough for me. Still I am interested in how to do this better, just for learnings and curiositys sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to deal with any files in DM-script (binary or text) is to use the streaming object. The following example should answer your question:

```c
void writeText()
{
 string path
 if ( !SaveAsDialog( "Save text as" , path , path ) ) return
 number fileID = CreateFileForWriting( path )
 object fStream = NewStreamFromFileReference( fileID , 1 )   // 1 for auto-close file when out of scope

 // Write some text
 number encoding = 0 // 0 = system default

 fStream.StreamWriteAsText( encoding , "The quick brown dog jumps over the lazy fox" )
 // Replace last 'fox' by 'dog'

 fStream.StreamSetPos( 1 , -3 )        // 3 bytes before current position
 fStream.StreamWriteAsText( encoding, "dog" )
 
 // Replace first 'dog' by 'fox'
 fStream.StreamSetPos( 0 , 16 )        // 16 bytes after start
 fStream.StreamWriteAsText( encoding, "fox" )

 // Append at end
 fStream.StreamSetPos( 2 , 0 )        // end position (0 bytes from end)
 fStream.StreamWriteAsText( encoding, "." )
}

writeText()
```